past tense vs. present perfect?

In his last game, his mistake (caused / has caused) his team to lose.

which is grammatically correct?
Is the answer the simple past tense because of the word "last" ?
Then is it impossible to use the present perfect tense?

The past tense is preferable to the perfect. There is nothing to support the situation as being of current relevance.

Choice of the past simple or present perfect depends on the context.
For example, if the context is a sports reporter commenting on the game immediately afterwards, then the present perfect is possible:

In his last game, his mistake has caused his team to lose.

In most other contexts, especially in written contexts that are inevitably more remote from the end of the game, then the past tense is far more natural:

In his last game, his mistake caused his team to lose.


And if this is a play-by-play, and this is known to be the player's last game ever, it could even be the present tense "is causing".

@Barmar. Yes. That's another context where an alternative to the past simple is feasible.

This depends on the circumstances and on your point of view.

(A Comprehensive Graammar of the English Language, Quirk et al. (1985) § 4.19)
[…]

I may have left the key at the office (last night). [5]

[…]
The overlap in the time-indicating functions of the past tense and the
present perfective is clearly seen in the choice of paraphrasing [5] above
either by the past tense [5a] or by the present perfective [5b]:

It is possible that I left the keys at the office (last night). [5a]
It is possible that I have left the keys at the office. [5b]



On the other hand, this example also shows that the present perfective is to
some extent limited by the fact that it shares the same past time 'territory' as the simple past. If a time-position adverbial like last night is added to [5], then the finite verb paraphrase has to be the past tense [5a] rather than the perfective [5b]. In other words, [5c] is unacceptable:

*It is possible that I have left the keys at the office last night. [5c]

However, the rule of adverbial incompatibility which forbids [5c] is
occasionally ignored; […]

The fact of having lost the keys is tense-wise strictly identical with the fact of causing the loss of a game. It can be seen the the only prescriptive condition is the use of a time position adverbial, which in the OP's sentence is not found; therefore both tenses are possible according as the speaker wants the listener to consider that the action is still effective at the time of speaking or not.

In his last game, his mistake caused / has caused his team to lose.
In his last game, an hour ago, his mistake caused  his team to lose.
In his last game, an hour ago,  his mistake  has caused his team to lose.


When I first saw this rule, I was a little bit confused. "Grammar for English Language Teachers" (Martin Parrot) -"We occasionally choose to use the present perfect simple with expressions of finished time (I have seen him yesterday) because, despite the adverb yesterday, we feel that the event is within a present time period. However, it would be confusing to draw learners` attention to examples like this. Page – 248.

@Beqa.  I have the second edition of Parrot's book where he uses a different example (I heard / have heard it twice yesterday.) He justifies the present perfect for the same reason (namely, the speaker feels the event is within "a present time frame"). Parrot claims ".. we need to recognize that such examples (i.e. of the present perfect usage) are relatively common." This claim surprises me somewhat. I assume however that, e.g.  I've heard about it twice yesterday is more common than I have heard about it twice yesterday. And that both are more common in spoken than in written text.
